# Why does operator-courier verify complain about mismatched versions?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to verify a CSV I built out for my Kubernetes operator using Operator Framework's operator-sdk. While doing that, I'm running into the following error.

What does this error from `operator-courier verify` mean?

```
ERROR: CRD.spec.version does not match CSV.spec.crd.owned.version
```

Answer (score 2):

This can occur if you simply have a CRD in your bundle that isn't mentioned in the CSV, but has a `spec.version` that isn't the same as the CSV.

Otherwise, you have a CSV that is probably something like this:

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterServiceVersion
spec:
  customeresourcedefinitions:
    owned:
    - name: something
    version: v1alpha1  <=================
```

and a CRD that is something like this

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: something
spec:
  version: v1alpha2  <===================
```

Those two versions need to align.

You might also see this in your installPlan's `status.conditions.message` if you get that far:

```
    CustomResourceDefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io
    "something.mycompany.com" is invalid: spec.version:
    Invalid value: "v1alpha2": must match the first version in spec.versions
```